# when calling vxCreateContext(): Error: _OpenDevice(1249): FATAL: Failed to open device, errno=No such file or directory

Tags: cross-compiling, toolchain, tflite, imx8

I am tring to cross-compile [tim-vx-imx](https://github.com/nxp-imx/tim-vx-imx.git). target machine is imx8plus from nxp. I have managed to obtain the ovxlib drivers (CLC, Gal, VSC, ArchModelSw, NNarchPerf, OpenVx and OpenVXU) from a prebuilt SDK [aarch64-poky-linux-gcc](https://owasys.sharepoint.com/sites/support/Documentos%20compartidos/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2Fsupport%2FDocumentos%20compartidos%2Fowa5x%2Fcompiler%2Ffsl%2Dimx%2Dxwayland%2Dglibc%2Dx86%5F64%2Dimx%2Dimage%2Dmultimedia%2Daarch64%2Dimx8mpevk%2Dtoolchain%2D5%2E4%2Dzeus%2Esh&parent=%2Fsites%2Fsupport%2FDocumentos%20compartidos%2Fowa5x%2Fcompiler&p=true&ga=1). When running the unit_test provided by tim-vx-imx, I get this error

Error:

```
[     1] Failed to open device: No such file or directory, Try again...                                                [     2] Failed to open device: No such file or directory, Try again...                                               [     3] Failed to open device: No such file or directory, Try again...                                                 [     4] Failed to open device: No such file or directory, Try again...                                                 [     5] OpenDevice(1249): FATAL: Failed to open device, errno=No such file or directory.
```

Comment: The problem was with missing kernel support for GPU/NPU. To fix it you need to re-compile the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with missing kernel support for GPU/NPU. To fix it you need to re-compile the kernel.